# Tengo un problema de logica al intentar eliminar de una lista letras e imprimir palabras que solo tengan las letras de esa lista en Java

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, java-8, sintaxis

que tengan buen dia. Tengo un problema en el que he estado trabajando para solucionar, resulta que tengo una lista con letras del abecedario de dos dimensiones que me toco aplanar usando Java funcional para que quede en un solo nivel y sea facil de aplanar, entonces lo que necesito es que de acuerdo a una palabra que yo le pase por parametros a la funcion que contiene el codigo, este codigo me permita:

1. Imprimir la palabra que todas sus letras esten en la lista
2. Cada vez que se imprima una palabra, las letras de esa palabra se deben eliminar de la lista para que no se puedan usar más
3. Por ultimo imprimir un mensaje que diga que la palabra no se puede imprimir porque le falta por lo menos una letra de la lista.

Entonces para hacer esto he creado el siguiente codigo, sin embargo estoy teniendo problemas en la validación del punto numero 3 y en el punto numero 2 cuando ingresa varias palabras diferentes por alguna razón la lista regresa ciertas letras que ya se tendrían que haber eliminado.

Agradecería mucho si algún estimado me pudiera ayudar con este problema:

```
public class Ejercicio {
    
    List<String> muestra= new ArrayList(); 
    
    public String getPalabra(String nombre) {
        
        //Lista con las letras del abecedario en dos niveles
        List<List<String>> programmers = Arrays.asList(
                   Arrays.asList("Z", "J"),
                   Arrays.asList("T", "H"),
                   Arrays.asList("A", "Q"),
                   Arrays.asList("C", "P"),
                   Arrays.asList("N", "A"),
                   Arrays.asList("E", "T"),
                   Arrays.asList("R", "E"),
                   Arrays.asList("T", "F"),
                   Arrays.asList("I", "D"),
                   Arrays.asList("L", "S"),
                   Arrays.asList("K", "U"),
                   Arrays.asList("V", "Q"));
                        
        //Aplanando la lista con las letras para que me quedeuna lista de 1 solo nivel:
        List<String> flatList = programmers.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.muestra=flatList;//Guardo en esta variable lo que va teniendo la lista
        
        String palabra = null; //Aqui guardare la palabra pasada por parametro


        //Entonces para cuando i sea menor al tamaño de nuestra lista inicial:
        for(int i= 0; i< flatList.size(); i++) {
            /*Si el nombre de la palabra contiene una de las letras que esta en la lista, 
            para traer la letra de una posicion de la lista se usa el flatList.get(i):*/
            if(nombre.contains(flatList.get(i))) {
    
                palabra= nombre; //Guardamos esa palabra en la variable palabra
                flatList.remove(i); //Y eliminamos la letra de la lista contenida en dicha palabra
            }

        }
        
        /*Devolvemos la palabra que fue admitida, es decir la que contiene alguna de las letras todavia 
         *disponibles en la lista:*/
        return "Palabra admitida: "+ palabra;
        
        }
    
        
    //Metodo para imprimir la cantidad de letras que van quedando en la lista:
        public List<String> getMuestra() {
            System.out.print("Letras que quedan de la lista: ");
            return this.muestra;
        }
    }
```

Este es el método main donde solamente por medio de un while reitero para ingresar cuantas palabras quisieramos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner entradaOpcion= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner entradaPalabra= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int opcion;     
        String palabra;

        Ejercicio resultado= new Ejercicio();

        do{
        System.out.print("\nEscoge una opcion:\n"
                + "1. Continuar \n"
                + "0. Salir"+"; \n"
                +"------------------------------------- \n");

        opcion= entradaOpcion.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Escribe una palabra");  
        palabra= entradaPalabra.nextLine();
        
        //Imprimimos y enviamos la palabra escrita en el Scanner al metodo getPalabra:
        System.out.println(resultado.getPalabra(palabra));
        
        //Acá vamos imprimiendo la lista para saber cuantas letras nos quedan:
        System.out.println(resultado.getMuestra());

        }while(opcion != 0);
        
    }
```

**Nota:** Talves el error que estoy teniendo es el condicional if en donde pregunta si la palabra pasado por parámetro contiene alguno de las letras de la lista, aunque no estoy seguro porque se supone que el metodo containes() itera la palabra para encontrar si tiene alguna letra en especifica

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando la lista "flatList" cada vez que llamas al método "getPalabra" y es por eso, que no ves que te elimine las letras (En realidad si las eliminas, pero al volver a llamar al método, vuelves a crear la lista).
Crea la lista en tu main antes del bucle while y pásala como parámetro al método getPalabra, de ese modo, trabajarás durante todas las iteraciones sobre la misma lista.

Respecto a cuando eliminas las letras en el bucle for, ten en cuenta, que estás alterando los indices y es probable que te de errores (Cuando eliminas, cambias el size de la lista y estás iterando sobre el size en el bucle for).

Para controlar si la palabra entera está dentro de la lista, puedes almacenar los índices que coinciden con las letras de la palabra y posteriormente, eliminarlos. Puedes hacer algo como lo que sigue:

```
        List<Integer> indicesEliminar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String elementos = "kjasdkjlasdab";
        
        String palabra ="aba"; //almacenar palabra

        for (int i = 0 ; i < palabra.length(); i++){
            int indice = elementos.indexOf(palabra.charAt(i));
            if (indice == -1) { //la letra no está en la cadena y por tanto, la palabra no es válida
                System.out.println("La letra: " + palabra.charAt(i) + " de la palabra: " + palabra + " no está en la lista");
                 break;
            }
            while (indice >= 0){
                if (!indicesEliminar.contains(elementos.indexOf(palabra.charAt(i), indice))){//Si el indice no está en los indices a eliminar
                    indicesEliminar.add(indice);
                   break;
                }
                indice = elementos.indexOf(palabra.charAt(i), indice+1); //volvemos a buscar tras la primera coincidencia.
            }       
        }
        
        
        
        if (indicesEliminar.size() == palabra.length()) {
            //Ordenamos los índices a eliminar, para eliminar de mayor a menor sin errores.
            Collections.sort(indicesEliminar);
            Collections.reverse(indicesEliminar);
            StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder(elementos);
            for (int i = 0; i < indicesEliminar.size(); i++) {
                cadena.deleteCharAt(indicesEliminar.get(i));
            }
            elementos = cadena.toString();
        }   
        else System.out.println("LA PALABRA NO ES VALIDA");
```